# Parse.com background job failure notification

Tags: parse-platform

I've scheduled a CloudCode script to run every night as a background job on parse.com. How I could make parse.com **notify me by e-mail** if my job fails? Of cause I could look into the logs, but I don't like to check them every day.

Comment: You could try integrating mail service like mailgun, mandrill to notify by mail.

Comment: Do you mean wrapping entire script in `try` block with an e-mail sending in `catch` block? Sounds like a plausible workaround. Are you absolutely sure Parse don't have this trivial feature hidden somewhere?

Comment: @AlexanderVasenin, I'm not sure if you use Parse, but try/catch is not applicable to asynchronous code, and thus is not useful for the majority of Parse tasks. Using this pattern would cause bugs and tears.

Answer (score 2):

The following is a simple example which use mailgun service to send email when job failed.

```
Parse.Cloud.job("backgroundJob", function(request, status) {
  // job code
  // ....
  }).then(function() {
    // Set the job's success status
    status.success("job completed successfully.");
  }, function(error) {
    // Set the job's error status
    status.error("Uh oh, something went wrong.");
    // send e-mail
    return Mailgun.sendEmail({
      to: "email@example.com",
      from: "Mailgun@CloudCode.com",
      subject: "Job failed!",
      text: "Job failed"
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: I'm not very experienced with async JavaScript, will I get an e-mail with this solution if my job failed because of, for example, trying to access the property of undefined object or something like this.

Comment: Why not validate it first?

Comment: Of cause I could validate what I know could go wrong, but some caveats are hard to predict so I would like to catch all possible bugs (not only the ones I'm expecting to appear).